# Using groupBy in Spark and getting back to a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a difficulty when working with data frames in spark with Scala. If I have a data frame that I want to extract a column of unique entries, when I use `groupBy` I don't get a data frame back.

For example, I have a `DataFrame` called logs that has the following form:

```
machine_id  | event     | other_stuff
 34131231   | thing     |   stuff
 83423984   | notathing | notstuff
 34131231   | thing    | morestuff
```

and I would like the unique machine ids where event is thing stored in a new `DataFrame` to allow me to do some filtering of some kind. Using

```
val machineId = logs
  .where($"event" === "thing")
  .select("machine_id")
  .groupBy("machine_id")
```

I get a val of Grouped Data back which is a pain in the butt to use (or I don't know how to use this kind of object properly). Having got this list of unique machine id's, I then want to use this in filtering another `DataFrame` to extract all events for individual machine ids.

I can see I'll want to do this kind of thing fairly regularly and the basic workflow is:

1. Extract unique id's from a log table.
2. Use unique ids to extract all events for a particular id.
3. Use some kind of analysis on this data that has been extracted.

It's the first two steps I would appreciate some guidance with here.

I appreciate this example is kind of contrived but hopefully it explains what my issue is. It may be I don't know enough about `GroupedData` objects or (as I'm hoping) I'm missing something in data frames that makes this easy. I'm using spark 1.5 built on Scala 2.10.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `distinct` not `groupBy`:

```
val machineId = logs.where($"event"==="thing").select("machine_id").distinct
```

Which will be equivalent to SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT machine_id FROM logs WHERE event = 'thing'
```

`GroupedData` is not intended to be used directly. It provides a number of methods, where `agg` is the most general, which can be used to apply different aggregate functions and convert it back to `DataFrame`. In terms of SQL what you have after `where` and `groupBy` is equivalent to something like this

```sql
SELECT machine_id, ... FROM logs WHERE event = 'thing' GROUP BY machine_id
```

where `...` has to be provided by `agg` or equivalent method.

Answer (score 1):

A group by in spark followed by aggregation and then a select statement will return a data frame. For your example it should be something like:

```
val machineId = logs
    .groupBy("machine_id", "event")
    .agg(max("other_stuff") )
    .select($"machine_id").where($"event" === "thing")
```