# Choosing random items from a Spark GroupedData Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to using Spark in Python and have been unable to solve this problem: After running `groupBy` on a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

```
df = sqlsc.read.json("data.json")
df.groupBy('teamId')
```

how can you choose `N` random samples from each resulting group (grouped by teamId) without replacement?

I'm basically trying to choose `N` random users from each team, maybe using `groupBy` is wrong to start with?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, it is kind of wrong. `GroupedData` is not really designed for a data access. It just describes grouping criteria and provides aggregation methods. See my answer to [Using groupBy in Spark and getting back to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33670195/1560062) for more details.

Another problem with this idea is selecting `N random samples`. It is a task which is really hard to achieve in parallel without psychical grouping of data and it is not something that happens when you `call` groupBy on a `DataFrame`:

There are at least two ways to handle this:

- convert to RDD, `groupBy` and perform local sampling

  ```
  import random

  n = 3

  def sample(iter, n): 
      rs = random.Random()  # We should probably use os.urandom as a seed
      return rs.sample(list(iter), n)    

  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      [(x, y, random.random()) for x in (1, 2, 3) for y in "abcdefghi"], 
      ("teamId", "x1", "x2"))

  grouped = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row.teamId, row)).groupByKey()

  sampled = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      grouped.flatMap(lambda kv: sample(kv[1], n)))

  sampled.show()

  ## +------+---+-------------------+
  ## |teamId| x1|                 x2|
  ## +------+---+-------------------+
  ## |     1|  g|   0.81921738561455|
  ## |     1|  f| 0.8563875814036598|
  ## |     1|  a| 0.9010425238735935|
  ## |     2|  c| 0.3864428179837973|
  ## |     2|  g|0.06233470405822805|
  ## |     2|  d|0.37620872770129155|
  ## |     3|  f| 0.7518901502732027|
  ## |     3|  e| 0.5142305439671874|
  ## |     3|  d| 0.6250620479303716|
  ## +------+---+-------------------+
  ```
- use window functions

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import Window
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rand, rowNumber

  w = Window.partitionBy(col("teamId")).orderBy(col("rnd_"))

  sampled = (df
      .withColumn("rnd_", rand())  # Add random numbers column
      .withColumn("rn_", rowNumber().over(w))  # Add rowNumber over windw
      .where(col("rn_") <= n)  # Take n observations
      .drop("rn_")  # drop helper columns
      .drop("rnd_"))

  sampled.show()

  ## +------+---+--------------------+
  ## |teamId| x1|                  x2|
  ## +------+---+--------------------+
  ## |     1|  f|  0.8563875814036598|
  ## |     1|  g|    0.81921738561455|
  ## |     1|  i|  0.8173912535268248|
  ## |     2|  h| 0.10862995810038856|
  ## |     2|  c|  0.3864428179837973|
  ## |     2|  a|  0.6695356657072442|
  ## |     3|  b|0.012329360826023095|
  ## |     3|  a|  0.6450777858109182|
  ## |     3|  e|  0.5142305439671874|
  ## +------+---+--------------------+
  ```

but I am afraid both will be rather expensive. If size of the individual groups is balanced and relatively large I would simply use `DataFrame.randomSplit`.

If number of groups is relatively small it is possible to try something else:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from operator import truediv

counts = (df
    .groupBy(col("teamId"))
    .agg(count("*").alias("n"))
    .rdd.map(lambda r: (r.teamId, r.n))
    .collectAsMap()) 

# This defines fraction of observations from a group which should
# be taken to get n values 
counts_bd = sc.broadcast({k: truediv(n, v) for (k, v) in counts.items()})

to_take = udf(lambda k, rnd: rnd <= counts_bd.value.get(k), BooleanType())

sampled = (df
    .withColumn("rnd_", rand())
    .where(to_take(col("teamId"), col("rnd_")))
    .drop("rnd_"))

sampled.show()

## +------+---+--------------------+
## |teamId| x1|                  x2|
## +------+---+--------------------+
## |     1|  d| 0.14815204548854788|
## |     1|  f|  0.8563875814036598|
## |     1|  g|    0.81921738561455|
## |     2|  a|  0.6695356657072442|
## |     2|  d| 0.37620872770129155|
## |     2|  g| 0.06233470405822805|
## |     3|  b|0.012329360826023095|
## |     3|  h|  0.9022527556458557|
## +------+---+--------------------+
```

In Spark 1.5+ you can replace `udf` with a call to `sampleBy` method:

```
df.sampleBy("teamId", counts_bd.value)
```

It won't give you exact number of observations but should be good enough most of the time as long as a number of observations per group is large enough to get proper samples. You can also use `sampleByKey` on a RDD in a similar way.

Comment: In case you cannot import `rowNumer`, it's `row_number` for me, could be because of a Pyspark update.

Answer (score 27):

I found this one more dataframey, rather than going into rdd way.

You can use `window` function to create ranking within a group, where ranking can be random to suit your case. Then, you can filter based on the number of samples `(N)` you want for each group

```
window_1 = Window.partitionBy(data['teamId']).orderBy(F.rand())
data_1 = data.select('*', F.rank().over(window_1).alias('rank')).filter(F.col('rank') <= N).drop('rank')
```

Comment: This is great, worked perfectly. I appreciate not needing to revert back to RDD for this.

Comment: Very nice and neat solution! +1

Comment: Is there any advantage here to using rank() instead of row_number()?

Comment: @wisdom_of_wombats check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using Pandas [DataFrame.Sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method. This uses the spark `applyInPandas` method to distribute the groups, available from Spark 3.0.0. This allows you to select an exact number of rows per group.

I've added `args` and `kwargs` to the function so you can access the other arguments of `DataFrame.Sample`.

```
def sample_n_per_group(n, *args, **kwargs):
    def sample_per_group(pdf):
        return pdf.sample(n, *args, **kwargs)
    return sample_per_group

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1.0), 
        (1, 2.0), 
        (2, 3.0), 
        (2, 5.0), 
        (2, 10.0)
    ],
    ("id", "v")
)

(df.groupBy("id")
   .applyInPandas(
        sample_n_per_group(2, random_state=2), 
        schema=df.schema
   )
)
```

To be aware of the limitations for very large groups, from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html):

> This function requires a full shuffle. All the data of a group will be
> loaded into memory, so the user should be aware of the potential OOM
> risk if data is skewed and certain groups are too large to fit in
> memory.

See also here:
[How take a random row from a PySpark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003314/how-take-a-random-row-from-a-pyspark-dataframe/69539847#69539847)