# How to select an exact number of random rows from DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, random, apache-spark-sql

How can I select an **exact** number of random rows from a DataFrame efficiently?
The data contains an index column that can be used.
If I have to use maximum size, what is more efficient, count() or max() on the index column?

Comment: can't you just use `df.sample()` ?

Comment: @mtoto sample() returns an approximate number, but algorithmics request an exact number in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible approach is to calculate the number of rows using `.count()`, then use `sample()` from `python`'s [random library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html) to generate a random sequence of arbitrary length from this range. Lastly use the resulting list of numbers `vals` to subset your index column.

```
import random 
def sampler(df, col, records):

  # Calculate number of rows
  colmax = df.count()

  # Create random sample from range
  vals = random.sample(range(1, colmax), records)

  # Use 'vals' to filter DataFrame using 'isin'
  return df.filter(df[col].isin(vals))
```

Example:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1,1),(2,1),
                     (3,1),(4,0),
                     (5,0),(6,1),
                     (7,1),(8,0),
                     (9,0),(10,1)]).toDF(["a","b"])

sampler(df,"a",3).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  3|  1|
|  4|  0|
|  6|  1|
+---+---+
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. This is something I've came to as well. The reason I didn't want to use this solution, is the use of **count()** method, that is very expensive.

Comment: you can also cache your `df` then compute `count()` outside the function, or use `agg(max)`.

Comment: Thanks, used your solution in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using Pandas [DataFrame.Sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method. This uses the spark `applyInPandas` method to distribute the groups, available from Spark 3.0.0. This allows you to select an exact number of rows per group.

I've added `args` and `kwargs` to the function so you can access the other arguments of `DataFrame.Sample`.

```
def sample_n_per_group(n, *args, **kwargs):
    def sample_per_group(pdf):
        return pdf.sample(n, *args, **kwargs)
    return sample_per_group

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1.0), 
        (1, 2.0), 
        (2, 3.0), 
        (2, 5.0), 
        (2, 10.0)
    ],
    ("id", "v")
)

(df.groupBy("id")
   .applyInPandas(
        sample_n_per_group(2, random_state=2), 
        schema=df.schema
   )
)
```

To be aware of the limitations for very large groups, from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html):

> This function requires a full shuffle. All the data of a group will be
> loaded into memory, so the user should be aware of the potential OOM
> risk if data is skewed and certain groups are too large to fit in
> memory.

See also here:
[How take a random row from a PySpark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003314/how-take-a-random-row-from-a-pyspark-dataframe/69539847#69539847)