# How to randomly selecting rows from one dataframeusing information from another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

The following I am attempting in Scala-Spark.

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on how to tackle this problem or provide me with some resources to figure out what I can do.

I have a `dateCountDF` with a count corresponding to a date. I would like to randomly select a certain number of entries for each `dateCountDF.month` from another Dataframe `entitiesDF` where `dateCountDF.FirstDate<entitiesDF.Date && entitiesDF.Date <= dateCountDF.LastDate` and then place all the results into a new Dataframe. *See Bellow for Data Example*

I'm not at all sure how to approach this problem from a Spark-SQl or Spark-MapReduce perspective. The furthest I got was the naive approach, where I use a `foreach` on a dataFrame and then refer to the other dataframe within the function. But this doesn't work because of the distributed nature of Spark.

```
val randomEntites = dateCountDF.foreach(x => {
  val count:Int = x(1).toString().toInt 
  val result = entitiesDF.take(count)
  return result
})
```

*DataFrames*

```
**dateCountDF**
|   Date   |      Count     |
+----------+----------------+
|2016-08-31|               4|
|2015-12-31|               1|
|2016-09-30|               5|
|2016-04-30|               5|
|2015-11-30|               3|
|2016-05-31|               7|
|2016-11-30|               2|
|2016-07-31|               5|
|2016-12-31|               9|
|2014-06-30|               4|
+----------+----------------+
only showing top 10 rows

**entitiesDF**
|    ID    |     FirstDate   | LastDate |
+----------+-----------------+----------+
|       296|       2014-09-01|2015-07-31|
|       125|       2015-10-01|2016-12-31|
|       124|       2014-08-01|2015-03-31|
|       447|       2017-02-01|2017-01-01|
|       307|       2015-01-01|2015-04-30|
|       574|       2016-01-01|2017-01-31|
|       613|       2016-04-01|2017-02-01|
|       169|       2009-08-23|2016-11-30|
|       205|       2017-02-01|2017-02-01|
|       433|       2015-03-01|2015-10-31|
+----------+-----------------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**Edit:**
For clarification.
My inputs are `entitiesDF` and `dateCountDF`. I want to loop through `dateCountDF` and for each row I want to select a random number of entities in `entitiesDF` where `dateCountDF.FirstDate<entitiesDF.Date && entitiesDF.Date <= dateCountDF.LastDate`

Comment: what is the input and what output you want can explain again with example

Comment: @RahulNirdhar  Thanks Rahul. See my added edit. Let me know if this clarifies things?

Comment: you got the answer of this

Answer (score 0):

To select random you do like this in scala

```
import random 
def sampler(df, col, records):

  # Calculate number of rows
  colmax = df.count()

  # Create random sample from range
  vals = random.sample(range(1, colmax), records)

  # Use 'vals' to filter DataFrame using 'isin'
  return df.filter(df[col].isin(vals))
```

select random number of rows you want store in dataframe and the add this data  in the another dataframe for this you can use unionAll.

also you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454334/how-to-select-an-exact-number-of-random-rows-from-dataframe)