# How to select n rows from large data set using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to select n rows from very large data set which has millions of rows. Let's say 4 million rows out of 15 million. Currently, I'm adding row_number to records within each partition and selecting the required percentage of records from each partition. For instance, 4 million is 26.66 % of 15 million. But when I'm trying to choose 26 % from each partition, the total number is going down because of the missing 0.6 %. As shown below, rows are selected when the **row_number** is less than **percentage**. Is there a better way to do this ?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `randonSplit`?

Comment: randomSplit is good option.In some scenarios I need exact number of sample records.

Answer (score 2):

dataframe sample function can be used. Solution available in below link
[How to select an exact number of random rows from DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454334/how-to-select-an-exact-number-of-random-rows-from-dataframe)