# Spark dataframe: collect () vs select ()

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Calling `collect()` on an RDD will return the entire dataset to the driver which can cause out of memory and we should avoid that.

Will `collect()` behave the same way if called on a dataframe?
What about the `select()` method?
Does it also work the same way as `collect()` if called on a dataframe?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[Actions vs Transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions)

> - Collect (Action) - Return all the elements of the dataset as an array at the driver program. This is usually useful after a filter or
>     other operation that returns a sufficiently small subset of the data.

[spark-sql doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

> **select(*cols)** (transformation) - Projects a set of expressions and returns a new DataFrame.
>
> Parameters:   cols – list of column names (string) or expressions
>   (Column). If one of the column names is ‘*’, that column is expanded
>   to include all columns in the current DataFrame.**
>
> ```
> df.select('*').collect()
> [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
> df.select('name', 'age').collect()
> [Row(name=u'Alice', age=2), Row(name=u'Bob', age=5)]
> df.select(df.name, (df.age + 10).alias('age')).collect()
> [Row(name=u'Alice', age=12), Row(name=u'Bob', age=15)]
> ```

Execution `select(column-name1,column-name2,etc)` method on a dataframe, returns a new dataframe which holds only the columns which were selected in the `select()` function.

e.g. assuming `df` has several columns including "name" and "value" and some others.

```
df2 = df.select("name","value")
```

`df2` will hold only two columns ("name" and "value") out of the entire columns of `df`

df2 as the result of `select` will be in the executors and not in the driver (as in the case of using `collect()`)

[sql-programming-guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

```
df.printSchema()
# root
# |-- age: long (nullable = true)
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)

# Select only the "name" column
df.select("name").show()
# +-------+
# |   name|
# +-------+
# |Michael|
# |   Andy|
# | Justin|
# +-------+
```

You can running `collect()` on a dataframe ([spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql))

```
>>> l = [('Alice', 1)]
>>> spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
[Row(_1=u'Alice', _2=1)]
>>> spark.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age']).collect()
[Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
```

[spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html)

> To print all elements on the driver, one can use the collect() method
>   to first bring the RDD to the driver node thus:
>   rdd.collect().foreach(println). **This can cause the driver to run out
>   of memory, though, because collect() fetches the entire RDD to a
>   single machine**; if you only need to print a few elements of the RDD, a
>   safer approach is to use the take(): rdd.take(100).foreach(println).

Comment: I feel like this is an excellent explanation of `select`, but I still don't feel like I understand what `collect` does.  What would all your examples be returning if you didn't have `collect()`?

Comment: @DanielKaplan _What would all your examples be returning if you didn't have collect()?_ : if the mentioned example didn't have `collect()` then I surmise all code would work just fine, only all the results would be given out in each individual worker, so let's say if in place of `rdd.collec().foreach(println)` we use `rdd.foreach()` then it would print all the rows in worker (maybe log files ), remember what we see in notebook is the output of driver and not worker. so we would not be able to see the output in notebook

Answer (score 10):

Calling `select` will result in lazy evaluation. For example:

```
val df1 = df.select("col1")
val df2 = df1.filter("col1 == 3")
```

Both above statements create lazy paths that will be executed when you call an action on that `df`, such as `show`, `collect` etc.

```
val df3 = df2.collect()
```

Use `.explain` at the end of your transformation to follow its plan.
Here is more detailed info: [Transformations and Actions](http://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

`Select` is used for projecting some or all fields of a `dataframe`. It won't give you an `value` as an output but a new `dataframe`. Its a `transformation`.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the questions directly:

> Will `collect()` behave the same way if called on a dataframe?

Yes, [`spark.DataFrame.collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#collect()) is functionally the same as [`spark.RDD.collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect()). They serve the same purpose on these different objects.

> What about the `select()` method?

There is no such thing as [`spark.RDD.select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html), so it cannot be the same as [`spark.DataFrame.select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)).

> Does it also work the same way as `collect()` if called on a dataframe?

The only thing that is similar between `select` and `collect` is that they are both functions on a DataFrame. They have absolutely zero overlap in functionality.

Here's my own description: `collect` is the opposite of `sc.parallelize`. `select` is the same as the `SELECT` in any SQL statement.

If you are still having trouble understanding what `collect` actually does (for either RDD or DataFrame), then you need to look up some articles about what spark is doing behind the scenes. e.g.:

- https://dzone.com/articles/how-spark-internally-executes-a-program
- https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-rdd-operations-transformations-actions/

Answer (score 5):

`Select` is a transformation, not an action, so it is lazily evaluated (won't actually do the calculations just map the operations). `Collect` is an action.

Try:

`df.limit(20).collect()`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer in bolds:

- `collect` is **mainly to serialize** 
  (loss  of parallelism preserving all other data characteristics of the dataframe)
  For example with a PrintWriter `pw` you can't do direct `df.foreach( r => pw.write(r) )`, must  to use `collect` before `foreach`, `df.collect.foreach(etc)`. 
  PS: the "loss of parallelism" is not a "total loss"  because after serialization it can be distributed again to executors.
- `select` is **mainly to select columns**, similar to [projection in relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) 
  (only similar in framework's context because Spark `select` not deduplicate data).
  So, it is also a complement of `filter` in the framework's context.

---

Commenting explanations of other answers: I like the [Jeff's classification of Spark operations](https://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf) in *transformations* (as `select`) and *actions* (as `collect`). It is also good remember that *transforms* (including `select`) are [lazily evaluated](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/11/28/view-based-collections.html).