# Scala groupBy to get a RDD[String, vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD in the form *RDD[((ID, code),value)]*

Example RDD:

```
((00001, 234) 7.0)
((00001, 456) 6.0)
((00001, 467) 3.0)
((00002, 245) 8.0)
((00002, 765) 9.0)
...
```

The Expected result *RDD[String, Vectors.dense(...))*

Example:

```
(00001, vector(7.0, 6.0, 3.0))
(00002, vector(8.0, 9.0))
```

I have tried the following:

```
val vectRDD = InRDD.groupBy(f => f._1._1)
  .map(m => (m._1, Vectors.dense(m._2._2)))
```

But get the below error:

```
value _2 is not a member of Iterable
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there – just missing the inner `map` from the 2nd tuple element to assemble the DenseVector:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (("00001", 234), 7.0),
  (("00001", 456), 6.0),
  (("00001", 467), 3.0),
  (("00002", 245), 8.0),
  (("00002", 765), 9.0)
))

rdd.
  groupBy(_._1._1).
  map(t => (t._1, Vectors.dense(t._2.map(_._2).toArray))).
  collect
// res1: Array[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)] =
//   Array((00001,[7.0,6.0,3.0]), (00002,[8.0,9.0]))
```

Note that `Vector.dense` takes an Array[Double], hence the `toArray`.

Comment: Leo C., Thanks again! I figured it out and had not looked here, but my code looks ugly compared to yours. One thing, I did't use collect.

Comment: looks like I need more, of something, to vote on things here. Tried to give an up vote on this one and the other you help me with.

Comment: @Al., I ran `collect` only to show the result of the minuscule sample data.  Normally you wouldn't perform `collect` unless you want to return all data to the driver program node.  To learn more about `collect`, here's a [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174747/spark-dataframe-collect-vs-select).

Comment: @Loe C., thanks for the link! I had a suspicion that collect had to do with collections. Oh, and can up vote now :)