# How to filter a second pyspark dataframe based on date value from other pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have a DataFrame where load_date_time is populated. I want to filter this dataframe with max(date_value) from some other DataFrame.

I have tried to do the following.

```
df2_max_create_date = df2.select("create_date").agg(F.max(df_dsa["create_date"]))
df2_max_create_date.show()
+----------------+
|max(create_date)|
+----------------+
|      2019-11-10|
+----------------+
```

then trying to filter the first dataframe based on this date. It has a timestamp column called load_date_time.

```
df_delta = df1.where(F.col('load_date_time') > (F.lit(df2_max_create_date)))
```

But I am getting below error.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: Just use a `join`. `df_delta = df1.alias("l").crossJoin(df2_max_create_date).where(F.col("load_date_time") > F.col("max(create_date)")).select("l.*")`.

Comment: works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `max_date` variable by calling `collect`:

```
max_create_date = df2.select(F.max(df_dsa["create_date"])).collect()[0][0]
df_delta = df1.where(F.col('load_date_time') > max_create_date)
```

Comment: FYI: Using a `join` would almost always be preferred to `collect`

Comment: @pault Got it! I understand why, too.

Comment: Why is it cost efficient to use a  cross join over a collect()?

Comment: @anidev711 Collect is an action, whereas a join is a transformation. Read this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174747/spark-dataframe-collect-vs-select