# How to select or drop a designated row in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, row

How to select or drop a designated row in pyspark dataframe?
such as drop third row in dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How take a random row from a PySpark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003314/how-take-a-random-row-from-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` or `filter` functions to achieve this as shown below:-

```
df.filter($"age" > 15)
df.where($"age" > 15)
```

## Update to drop by column index

```
val col = df.columns
val n   = df.columns.length 
val toBeDropped = n-1 // to drop last column  and so on..
val oldDf = df.drop(col(ToBeDropped ))
```

Comment: I want drop a column by index

Comment: I have updated the answer, if this was helpful pls do accept the answer.

Comment: That is not possible without getting all the rows in the driver which will lead OOM errors if the data is large. The best way to do would be to use the `filter` statement and programmatically determining the condition