# Selective sampling in spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD from logged events I wanted to take few samples of each category.

Data is like below

```
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type1|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type2|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type3|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type3|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type4|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type1|xxxx|xxxx
|xxx|xxxx|xxxx|type6|xxxx
```

My try

```
eventlist = ['type1', 'type2'....]
orginalRDD = sc.textfile("/path/to/file/*.gz").map(lambda x: x.split("|"))

samplelist = []
for event in event list:
    eventsample = orginalRDD.filter(lambda x: x[3] == event).take(5).collect()
    samplelist.extend(eventsample)

print samplelist
```

I have two questions on this,
    1. Some better way/efficient way to collect sample based on specific condition?
    2. Is it possible to collect the unsplit lines instead of splitted lines?

Python or scala suggestion are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sample doesn't have to be random something like this should work just fine:

```py
n = ...  # Number of elements you want to sample
pairs =  orginalRDD.map(lambda x: (x[3], x))

pairs.aggregateByKey(
    [],  # zero values
    lambda acc, x: (acc + [x])[:n],  # Add new value a trim to n elements
    lambda acc1, acc2: (acc1 + acc2)[:n])  # Combine two accumulators and trim
```

Getting a random sample is a little bit harder. One possible approach is to add a random value and sort before aggregation:

```py
import os
import random

def add_random(iter):
   seed = int(os.urandom(4).encode('hex'), 16)
   rs = random.Random(seed)
   for x in iter:
       yield (rs.random(), x)

(pairs
    .mapPartitions(add_random)
    .sortByKey()
    .values()
    .aggregateByKey(
        [],
        lambda acc, x: (acc + [x])[:n],
        lambda acc1, acc2: (acc1 + acc2)[:n]))
```

For a `DataFrame` specific solution see [Choosing random items from a Spark GroupedData Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33749965/1560062)

Comment: Great, let me try this thanks and does it check for aggregation of x[3] in complete RDD? coz RDD is created from 1TB of S3 gz compressed files.