# Spark- select random rows with conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df like below, and I need to select rows based on certain preferences within each `prod_name`. For `prod_name = A`, randomly select 3 rows. same for `B` and `C`, base on a preferred colour `blue, green, yellow, red`. For example if there are `blue`, then the rows with `blue` would be selected first, followed by `green` etc. The problem is, with `prod_name = A`, there are too many rows with `blue`. I need to put a limit to say `for product A, randomly only select 2 rows with blue if there are any, and then select other colours based on the preferred order`

I can sort of understand how to randomly select rows within a window based on the last answer from [Choosing random items from a Spark GroupedData Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749965/choosing-random-items-from-a-spark-groupeddata-object), but really not sure how to put a limit on certain colour and how to get things together. Could someone please help? Many thanks in advance.

```
prod_name | colour | prod_id   
-------------------------------
  A      | blue    |100        
  A      | blue    |200
  A      | blue.   |300
  A      | blue.   |300
  A      | yellow. |309
  B      | green.  |408
  B      | blue.   |50
  C      | red.    |6000
  C      | blue    |70
  C      | green   |10
```

Comment: So for A in the example, you'd expect only 3 random rows for color blue as output?

Comment: for A in example, 3 random rows but only 2 with blue.