# How to filter certain percentage of data from a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyspark

I have a table where i have a column Groups.

```
  Groups
   --------
  |GroupA  |
  |GroupB  |
  |GroupC  |
  |GroupA  |
  |GroupB  |
   --------
```

Lets say i have 2000 records of GroupA, 1000 records of GroupB and 1000 records of GroupC. Also this values would change everyday. How can i extract 5% of data from each of this using sql or pyspark. Am mostly looking for something in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:** If you want a 5% sample from entire data set.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com") \
    .getOrCreate()

df=spark.range(100)
print(df.sample(0.05).collect())
```

0.05 represents 5% of data.

**Scenario 2**: If you want 5% of each group:

```
def sample_n_per_group(n, *args, **kwargs):
    def sample_per_group(pdf):
        return pdf.sample(n, *args, **kwargs)
    return sample_per_group

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1.0), 
        (1, 2.0), 
        (2, 3.0), 
        (2, 5.0), 
        (2, 10.0)
    ],
    ("id", "v")
)

(df.groupBy("id")
   .applyInPandas(
        sample_n_per_group(2, random_state=2), 
        schema=df.schema
   )
)
```

Ref: [Choosing random items from a Spark GroupedData Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749965/choosing-random-items-from-a-spark-groupeddata-object)